# En un procedimiento almacenado, ¿cómo listar diferentes registros en un mismo listado?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

una pregunta.

Supongamos un procedimiento sencillo como el siguiente:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE simple_loop ( ) 
BEGIN
  DECLARE counter BIGINT DEFAULT 0;

  my_loop: LOOP
    SET counter=counter+1;

    SELECT counter;

    IF counter=10 THEN
      LEAVE my_loop;
    END IF;

  END LOOP my_loop;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Si llamamos a ese procedimiento se mostrarán 10 resultados independientes. Ahora bien, ¿cómo podríamos hacer para que dichos resultados se almacenaran y mostraran en una misma consulta/listado?

No sé si me explico, imagino que la pregunta es un poco tonta. Me surge el problema  à la hora de crear un procedimiento similar un poco más complejo, para ir sacando los registros que cumplen unas ciertas condiciones, pero no cada uno en un resultado

Muchas gracias.

Comment: dentro del loop debes traer los datos y cuando lo hagas, los conparas con un if y si es el que necesitas lo almacenas en una variable

Comment: O podrias crear una tabla temporal e insertar los resultados que necesites

Comment: Efectivamente, hay varias alternativas (tabla temporal, JSON (en versiones recientes), entre otras) para listar diferentes registros en un mismo listado, sin embargo, ¿por qué no puede generar el listado desde una única consulta?, ¿qué caso de uso se le presenta?.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una tabla temporal con la siguiente sintaxis ([ver referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html)):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    (create_definition,...)
    [table_options]
    [partition_options]
```

y luego ir insertando en tu tabla temporal con la sentencia INSERT INTO ([ver referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html))

Y al final del procedimiento haces un select y retorna todos los datos que insertaste:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name
```

Cabe resaltar que tbl_name es el nombre de tu tabla temporal